# Capturing value in submitted form in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have multiple identical forms on a page and I'm trying to pass the value of a hidden field that has the id idJoueur of the specific form that is submitted with the following code. Currently, I'm only succeeding in passing it the value of the first one, no matter which one is clicked.

```js
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        var tramodifier = $("#idJoueur").val(); //variable to be populated from the
        //specific form which is posted
        alert(tramodifier); //alert for testing purposes
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
            $("#result").html(data);
        });
        e.preventDefault();
        $("tr^=#" + tramodifier).css("background-color", "grey");
    });
});​
```

Example of html

```html
<form action="/Admin/Match/LaCreation/1" id="1" method="post">
    <td style="width: 1px;">
        <input data-val="true" data-val-number="Le champ Int32 doit &amp;#234;tre un nombre." data-val-required="Le champ Int32 est requis." id="idJoueur" name="idJoueur" type="hidden" value="1" />....other stuff
        <input id=1 class='ajax_multi_submit' type="submit" value="Créer" />
        </p>
    </td>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: You should never have the same ID for more than one element on your page.  I would suggest adding a prefix to your IDs, something like "idJoueur_1" or use a name and your submitted form as jQuery's context.

Answer (score 0):

Get the form that was submitted using the `this` keyword and find the element within the form using one of these techniques:

```
$(this).children('#idJoueur').val();
```

or

```
$(this).find('#idJoueur').val();
```

I'm actually not sure if one is better than the other; they both worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, these techniques do not work. You probably are right about id vs class but it is created automatically via the MVC framework. I don't seem to have control over this.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `var tramodifier = $("#idJoueur").val();` you should do this:

```
var tramodifier = $(this).find('#idJoueur').val();
```

In addition, you should change your attribute from id to class. The selector will then be .idJoueur instead.

`.find` does a search within the element's children. By using the context of the submitted form like this, you can easily extract the right hidden field. Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/find/

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved it. As I'm also passing the idJoueur to the form, that's where I've picked it up.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (e) {
         var tramodifier = $(this).attr("value");
            $.post($(this).attr("action"),
                $(this).serialize(),
                    function (data) {
                        $("#result").html(data);
                    });
            e.preventDefault(); 
            $("tr^=." + tramodifier).css("background-color", "grey");
        });
    });

</script>
```